# Crontab Django Management command seems to start but nothing happens

Tags: python, django, cron

I have defined a django management command that imports some data into my application database. I run it using a crontab. Sidenote: everything is inside a docker container. This command works perfectly when I use it manually in my container's shell. However, when crontab tries to run it, nothing happens.

My crontab line is the following :

```
* * * * * nice -n 19 /usr/local/bin/python3 /code/manage.py my_command "a string argument for my command" # a comment to find the cron easily
```

(I put my code into /code because it seemed a good idea at the time.)

I know that crontab calls my command, because /var/log/syslog displays when it is executed. I cannot fathom the reason why nothing happens.

As a test in the "handle" method of my command, I wrote `print("handling command")` as the first line then added `>> /code/cron.log` at the end of my crontab line. The text didn't appear in the file.

Any idea ?

### **EDIT**

I added some "print" statements in manage.py and they appeared in the log file. These prints work until the `execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)` statement. Which means something goes wrong in this function (imported from django.core.management).

I'll keep on investigating.

### **EDIT 2**

After printing lots of stuff in the Django framework, I got to my apps.py file in the AppConfig.ready method. In here, I had defined a function that starts the cron service if it isn't already up. In order to do that, I used subprocess.Popen tu run `service cron status`.

At this point, the cron execution goes no further.
I do not understand exactly why it stops there, but it seems to me that cron refuses to spawn new processes.
(I had that function in AppConfig.ready because I read that this code was executed only once.)

Answer (score 0):

What stopped the cron execution was that I run a command in subprocess.Popen that did not use absolute paths. So Popen (which I didn't put inside a try .. except) crashed when call with the small cron environment variables.

I would not have thought to look there, because this part of code was called from my AppConfig.ready method.

I hope this can help someone, please tell me if you think I should remove this post, I'll do so when I get the notification.